# What is a idempotent matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to know what is a idempotent matrix? Also, which invertible matrices are also idempotent and can a matrix be nilpotent and idempotent at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. *In algebra, an idempotent matrix is a matrix which, when multiplied by itself, yields itself.* (guess where this is from...)
2. *With the exception of the identity matrix, an idempotent matrix is singular...*
3. Does the zero matrix count?

Comment: In fact, there are exactly three kinds of idempotant matrices: the unit matrix (invertible), the zero matrix (nilpotent) and all others (neither).